# Clicking UIButton after Disabling its user interaction causes collection view cell being selected

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell and a button as its subview. If you click the cell it goes to the detail page. And if you click the button it adds the item to the basket. I need to block the button from clicking more than 1. So I am disabling the button for a few seconds. But this time if I click the button before the delay ends, it goes to the detail page from the button too. Is there a way to solve this without disabling the cell itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom delegate as call back in cell that will let the `ViewController` know that button is disable when user will tap on button. Store that disable state in some store property of `ViewController`.

let say `flag = false`

After that when user will tap cell `didSelect` delegate will get trigger. Then add there a check `if flag == false` do nothing and vice versa.

After few seconds change the stat of flag i.e. `flag = true`.
In this way you will not need to disable the cell and you can perform other events there.

Just giving you an idea as I cannot see you code I hope this will help.